# How to cancel odoo sales order via API

Tags: odoo

How can I cancel a sales order using the Odoo API? I thought I would be able to call the `action_cancel` method since that is the method the cancel button calls from the UI.

I tried doing it like this:

```
self::$modelClient->execute_kw(self::$db, self::$uid, self::$password, 'sale.order', 'action_cancel', [123]);
```

However, I get an error response:

```
TypeError: cannot marshal None unless allow_none is enabled
```

It appears that the sale order IS actually cancelled, but I get that error as a response. Does anyone know what that error means?

I just want to be sure the order is correctly cancelled, and the error makes me think something went wrong.

Comment: https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/ayuda-1/cancel-sales-order-after-delivered-items-109748

Answer (score 0):

The following code will cancel all sale orders via the XML-RPC API (e.g. using Python):

```py
sale_orders = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,'sale.order', 'search_read', [[]],{'fields':['id']})
for so in sale_orders:
    models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,'sale.order', 'write', [so['id'], {'state':'cancel'}])
```

If you only want to cancel one sale_order with id so_id, use instead:

```py
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,'sale.order', 'write', [so_id,{'state':'cancel'}])
```

Disclaimer: I tested this code with purchase.order, but I believe it will behave similarly for sale.order